# Sceneform Transparent Material

Tags: android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

**Goal**

Transparent material for a cube renderable created with ShapeFactory.

**Tried**

```
MaterialFactory.makeTransparentWithColor(context, Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)).thenAccept { material ->

    val size = Vector3(100f,0.001f,100f)
    val center = Vector3(0f,0f,0f)
    val floorRenderable = ShapeFactory.makeCube(size,center,material)
    floorRenderable.isShadowCaster = false
    floorRenderable.isShadowReceiver = false

    floorAnchorNode.renderable = floorRenderable
}
```

So for Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f), the cube does not become invisible, even though it is a little bit transparent.

I have also tried the following with the same result.

```
context.getColor(R.color.transparent)
```

where

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not fully transparent simply because of lighting.

If you need to make something invisible, don't set any renderable. And if you simply want to intercept touch, use collision instead :

```
floorAnchorNode.collisionShape = Box(size, center)
```